# THREE.js slope detection

Tags: javascript, three.js, webgl

I want to ask that how we can detect the slope in a car game. so that car detect it as a slope not as a collide-able object. I searched a lot but can't find any thing useful or helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your description of the situation is a little vague, in terms of physics packages etc (or are your writing one?), but in general I would say that the simplest way to define a sloping terrain is as a height field -- a rectangular mesh of triangles. So make a N x M array of different heights, and then have Three.js draw triangles whose height (Y) matches the values of the array, and spaced... however far apart you like, depending on the requirements you may have for terrain detail.

Now for any given car position, you can quickly determine in JS the three closest points in the mesh based solely on the X and Z components of the car position. This is just a couple of divisions against your mesh spacing. Once you have these, then your JS code can adjust the height of the car to the appropriate Y for that location on the triangle, and if you have physics solutions that need to know the 3D slope of that location, it's also easy to calculate. Three.js itself doesn't even need to be called -- all the crucial info is in the original terrain array and the 2D-mapped-to-3D position of the car.

This is a solution *specifically* for terrain -- if you want to be able to collide-or-not with arbitrary geometry, well that is considerably more complex.